# How to get detail table records as string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table in database which contains hospital names as follow:

```
+------------+--------------+
| HospitalID | HospitalName |
+------------+--------------+
|          1 | Hosp1        |
|          2 | Hosp2        |
|          3 | Hosp3        |
|          4 | Hosp4        |
+------------+--------------+
```

Another table also exist which contains activity names as follows:

```
+------------+--------------+
| ActivityID | ActivityName |
+------------+--------------+
|          1 | Act1         |
|          2 | Act2         |
|          3 | Act3         |
|          4 | Act4         |
|          5 | Act5         |
+------------+--------------+
```

There's a N*M relation between these tables, i.e. each hospital can operate different activities. Therefore another table is required as follows:

```
+----+------------+------------+
| ID | HospitalID | ActivityID |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 |          1 |          1 |
|  2 |          1 |          2 |
|  3 |          1 |          5 |
|  4 |          2 |          1 |
|  5 |          2 |          3 |
|  6 |          3 |          2 |
+----+------------+------------+
```

I want to write a select statement which selects hospital names and their related activities in a string field as follows:

```
+--------------+------------------+
| HospitalName |  ActivityNames   |
+--------------+------------------+
| Hosp1        | Act1, Act2, Act5 |
| Hosp2        | Act1, Act3       |
| Hosp3        | Act2             |
| Hosp4        |                  |
+--------------+------------------+
```

I have written the select statement using a function for ActivityNames field using a cursor but it is not optimized and the system performance decreases as the number of records increases.

Any solution or suggestion on how to solve this problem?

Comment: First suggestion - upgrade your database. Sql server 2005 is no longer supported by Microsoft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this just with a select. No need of looping or Cursor for this. Looping will make performance degrade.

So the Schema will be

```
CREATE TABLE #HOSPITAL( HOSPITALID INT, HOSPITALNAME VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #HOSPITAL
SELECT 1, 'HOSP1' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 , 'HOSP2' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 3 ,'HOSP3' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 4 , 'HOSP4' 



CREATE TABLE #ACTIVITY( ActivityID INT, ActivityName VARCHAR(50) )

INSERT INTO #ACTIVITY                          
SELECT          1,  'Act1'    
UNION ALL     
SELECT          2,  'Act2'  
UNION ALL        
SELECT          3,  'Act3' 
UNION ALL         
SELECT          4,  'Act4'
UNION ALL          
SELECT          5,  'Act5'         


CREATE TABLE #HOSPITAL_ACT_MAP(ID INT, HospitalID INT, ActivityID INT)

INSERT INTO #HOSPITAL_ACT_MAP
SELECT 1, 1, 1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2, 1, 2 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 3, 1, 5 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 4, 2, 1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 5, 2, 3 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 6, 3, 2
```

And do Select like below with CTE

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT DISTINCT H.HOSPITALNAME, A.ActivityName FROM #HOSPITAL_ACT_MAP HA
INNER JOIN #HOSPITAL H ON HA.HospitalID = H.HOSPITALID
INNER JOIN #ACTIVITY A ON HA.ActivityID = A.ActivityID
)

SELECT  HOSPITALNAME
, (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ','+ActivityName FROM CTE C1 
WHERE  C1.HOSPITALNAME = C.HOSPITALNAME 
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')) 
FROM CTE C
GROUP BY HOSPITALNAME
```

**Edit from Comments**

If you can't use `CTE` and `Stuff` go for **Method 2**

```
DECLARE @TAB TABLE (HOSPITALNAME VARCHAR(20),ActivityName VARCHAR(20) )

INSERT INTO @TAB
SELECT DISTINCT H.HOSPITALNAME, A.ActivityName FROM #HOSPITAL_ACT_MAP HA
INNER JOIN #HOSPITAL H ON HA.HospitalID = H.HOSPITALID
INNER JOIN #ACTIVITY A ON HA.ActivityID = A.ActivityID

SELECT HOSPITALNAME, SUBSTRING(ACTIVITIES,1, LEN(ACTIVITIES)-1) FROM(

SELECT DISTINCT HOSPITALNAME,(SELECT ActivityName+',' FROM @TAB T1 
WHERE  T1.HOSPITALNAME = T.HOSPITALNAME 
FOR XML PATH('') ) AS ACTIVITIES FROM @TAB T

)A
```

**Note:** For the performance purpose I have stored the Intermediate result on @TAB (Table variable). If you want you can directly Query it with Sub Query.

Comment: Not sure sql server 2005 supports `stuff`, pretty sure it doesn't support cte. but I seem to remember it does support `for xml`...

Comment: The written method with CTE and STUFF worked fine for me in either SQL Server 2005 and 2008. Thanks for your valuable comments.

Comment: @shahram Akbarinasaji,you used inner join.Then how you get 'HOSP4' value.It not linked with activity and mapping.

Comment: @ShakeerMirza,you used inner join.Then how you get 'HOSP4' value.It not linked with activity and mapping.

Comment: @Mansoor OP's intention to get the list of Activities in comma concatenation for hospitals. If we need we can have a LEFT JOIN

Comment: @Mansoor , changing <inner join #Hospital> to <right outer join> will solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
using STUFF function to achieve your result :

CREATE TABLE #Hospital(HospitalID INT,HospitalName VARCHAR(100))
CREATE TABLE #Activity(ActivityID INT,ActivityName VARCHAR(100))
CREATE TABLE #RelationShip(Id INT,HospId INT,ActId INT)
CREATE TABLE #ConCat(HospitalID  INT ,HospName VARCHAR(100), ActName   
VARCHAR(100),UpFlag TINYINT DEFAULT(0))
DECLARE @HospId INT = 0,@String VARCHAR(200) = ''

INSERT INTO #Hospital(HospitalID ,HospitalName )
SELECT 1,'Hosp1' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Hosp2' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Hosp3' UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'Hosp4'    

INSERT INTO #Activity(ActivityID ,ActivityName )
SELECT  1,'Act1' UNION ALL 
SELECT  2,'Act2' UNION ALL 
SELECT  3,'Act3' UNION ALL 
SELECT  4,'Act4' UNION ALL 
SELECT  5,'Act5' 

INSERT INTO #RelationShip(ID,HospId,ActId)
SELECT  1 ,          1 ,          1 UNION ALL
SELECT    2 ,          1 ,          2 UNION ALL
SELECT    3 ,          1 ,          5 UNION ALL
SELECT    4 ,          2 ,          1 UNION ALL
SELECT    5 ,          2 ,          3 UNION ALL
SELECT    6 ,          3 ,          2 

SELECT HospitalName , STUFF(  ( SELECT  ',' + ActivityName FROM #Activity   
JOIN #RelationShip ON ActId = ActivityID WHERE HospId = HospitalID FOR XML   
PATH('') ),1,1,'')  
FROM #Hospital
GROUP BY HospitalID,HospitalName 

***FOR SQLServer2005 Use below code***

  INSERT INTO #ConCat (HospitalID ,HospName) 
  SELECT DISTINCT HospitalID ,HospitalName 
  FROM #Hospital

  WHILE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #ConCat WHERE UpFlag = 0)
  BEGIN

     SELECT @HospId =  HospitalID FROM #ConCat WHERE UpFlag = 0 ORDER BY   
     HospitalID

     SET @String = ''
     SELECT @String = ISNULL(@String,'') + CAST(A.ActivityName AS VARCHAR) +    
     ',' FROM 
      (
        SELECT ActivityName 
        FROM #RelationShip 
        JOIN #Activity ON ActId = ActivityID
        WHERE HospId = @HospId
      ) A 

      UPDATE #ConCat SET UpFlag = 1,ActName = CASE WHEN @String = '' THEN    
       @String ELSE SUBSTRING(@String,0,LEN(@String) ) END WHERE HospitalID    
       = @HospId

     END

     SELECT * FROM #ConCat
```

Comment: Not sure sql server 2005 supports `stuff`, but I seem to remember it does support `for xml`...

Comment: @ZoharPeled 2005 supports stuff

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Good to know, in case I'll ever invent that time machine :-)

Comment: but in this microsoft document stated that it is supported from 2008 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx @t-clausen.dk

Comment: @ShakeerMirza seeks you are right. I was using this [link](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/stuff.php)

Answer (score -1):

You can use json to increase the performance of front end.
There is no particular solution if you are using open source databases.

Try to use IBM db2 or  ORACLE database to ensure performance of your app.

then generate json data . You will find the improvement in speed

Comment: Faruk he already tag Sqlserver, so give answer based on that.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2005 as a database server. My problem is how to obtain ActivityNames field. Would you mind providing more detailed info?